Как установить и добавить версию Qt 4.8.7
Делаю проекты на Qt, использую версию Qt6 как основную, сейчас нужно открыть и доработать проект на Qt 4.8.7. Пробовал загрузить эту версию через Qt maintainance tool но такой версии там нет. Подскажите где загрузить и как добавить в Qt creator версию Qt 4.8.7

качать из архива https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.7/
